# how to use barycentric coordinates for polygons

Tags: barycentric-coordinates

suppose we want to deal with the problems with a sided polygons then how can we proceed in barycentric coordinates,

that is how can we fame the coordinates of the hexagon in barycentric coordinates.

Comment: "Generalized baycentric coordinates".  Lots of literature at https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=generalized+barycentric+coordinates&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact problem, but assuming a plane polygon, then any three non-collinear vertices of the polygon determine a triangle of reference for a
[barycentric coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). You could use instead any other three non-collinear points in the plane of the polygon. Any points in the plane determined by the triangle, and hence the polygon vertices, will be an [affine combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination) of the the reference triangle vertices.

For example, if $\, p_1,p_2,p_3 \,$ are the three reference points, with their existing ordinary coordinates, and $\, p \,$ is a point in the same plane, then $\, p = a_1 p_1 + a_2 p_2 + a_3 p_3 \,$ for some real numbers such that $\, 1 = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \,$ and their values can be determined by solving  a system of linear equations using the existing coordinates.

Comment: Thank you somos, suppose if I want to deal with hexagon, how can I keep the coordinates of 6 vertices in the bary centric coordinates